# Install gdal geodjango on elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, gdal, geodjango

what are the correct steps to install geodjango on elastic beanstalk?
got eb instance, installed env and made it two instances now I want to use geodjango on it, I'm already using it on a separate ec2 instance for testing

that's my django.config file and it fails

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
        WSGIPath: hike.project.wsgi:application

commands:
    01_gdal:
        command: "wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.1.3/gdal-2.1.3.tar.gz && tar -xzf gdal-2.1.3.tar.gz && cd gdal-2.1.3 && ./configure && make && make install"
```

then tried this instead and also failed from 100% cpu and time limit

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
        WSGIPath: hike.project.wsgi:application

commands:
  01_install_gdal:
    test: "[ ! -d /usr/local/gdal ]"
    command: "/tmp/gdal_install.sh"
files:
  "/tmp/gdal_install.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
      sudo yum -y install make automake gcc gcc-c++ libcurl-devel proj-devel geos-devel

      # Geos
      cd /
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/geos
      cd usr/local/geos/geos-3.7.2
      sudo wget geos-3.7.2.tar.bz2 http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.7.2.tar.bz2
      sudo tar -xvf geos-3.7.2.tar.bz2
      cd geos-3.7.2
      sudo ./configure
      sudo make
      sudo make install
      sudo ldconfig

      # Proj4
      cd /
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/proj
      cd usr/local/proj
      sudo wget -O proj-5.2.0.tar.gz http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-5.2.0.tar.gz
      sudo wget -O proj-datumgrid-1.8.tar.gz http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-datumgrid-1.8.tar.gz
      sudo tar xvf proj-5.2.0.tar.gz
      sudo tar xvf proj-datumgrid-1.8.tar.gz
      cd proj-5.2.0
      sudo ./configure
      sudo make
      sudo make install
      sudo ldconfig

      # GDAL
      cd /
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/gdal
      cd usr/local/gdal
      sudo wget -O gdal-2.4.4.tar.gz http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.4.4/gdal-2.4.4.tar.gz
      sudo tar xvf gdal-2.4.4.tar.gz
      cd gdal-2.4.4
      sudo ./configure
      sudo make
      sudo make install
      sudo ldconfig
```

and I've no idea what to do,

Answer (score 0):

For others who also searching for answer, I just used docker-compose

EB will by default use docker-compose.yml when you put it in the root folder

Dockerfile

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.9.16-slim-buster

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/gunicorn/
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/gunicorn/

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y libgdal-dev


# install dependencies 
COPY ./requirements.txt /srv/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /srv/requirements.txt

COPY . .

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
   
services:
    django:
        build: .
        container_name: django
        command: gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 project.wsgi:application
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:8000"
```

and that's it